# Does anyone know a way to draw lines connecting nearest neighbor points in ListPlot[ ]?

Tags: visualization, plotting

I have a two-dimensional mesh that I am visualizing in Mathematica, with ListPlot[]. The mesh looks like this:

[image]

Any ideas for how to connect all the nearest neighboring points with lines?

Thanks, ahead of time.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: If the purpose is to recreate some triangulated mesh from points - you can use e.g. DelaunayMesh.

Comment: Thanks! This was my purpose. I will keep this in mind in the future. I actually wound up figuring a way to visualize the mesh within the program I started using to create the mesh. "gmsh". But this will still be useful for me in the future!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ListPlot[]` isn't the "right" tool. It can be done with `Epilog ->`, but it's more natural to use `Graphics[]` and `Nearest[]`:

```
(*  Generate a distribution similar to your example *)
n = 1000;
rs = RandomVariate[TransformedDistribution[Sqrt@x,x\[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{.1, 1}]], n];
phis = RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, n];
pts = #1 {Cos@#2, Sin@#2} & @@@ Transpose[{rs, phis}];

(* Find the lines and plot them*)
p = Nearest[pts];
pts1 = p[#, 2][[2]] & /@ pts;
Graphics[{Point@pts, Line[{##}] & @@@ Transpose[{pts, pts1}]},  Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The standard doc for `Nearest[]` is not complete. [This one](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/UsingNearest.html) is much better.

If you want something like "percolation style" neighbors (almost, but not exactly), you can do:

```
k = {};
AppendTo[k, {#, (h = p[#, 100])[[2 + 
        Sum[Boole@MemberQ[k, {h[[i]], #}], {i, 2, 100}]]]}] & /@ pts;
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]